# How to solve system of linear congruences without using inverse integers?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, linear-diophantine-equations

Suppose I have a set of linear congruences with their modules being relatively prime. Is there an elementary way to solve these without using the inverse properties of modular integers?

Ex. Solving 
x congruent to 3mod17
x congruent to 10mod16
x congruent to 0mod15

I know the result, by brute force. I also know since the mod's are pair wise incongruent , that there exists a unique solution mod (15*16*17).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a possibility, but it is like shooting rockets on ants :)

Suppose, $a$ and $n$ are coprime.

Since we have $a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1\ (\ mod\ n)$ , we could calculate

$$a^{\phi(n)-1}\equiv a^{-1}\ (\ mod\ n)$$

Comment: What is phi(n)?

Comment: Note, that we do not explicit use the inverse with this approach.

Comment: $\phi(n)$ is the Euler-phi-function, giving the number of residues in the range [1,n-1] coprime to $n$

Comment: For $n$ with known factorization, in particular prime $n$, the method you mention is not terrible, if we use the binary method of modular exponentiation.

Comment: Unfortunately, we have no knowledge on that haha.

Comment: @Michael Cera Why do you want a solution without inverses ?

Comment: Because we haven't learned that in our course and our professor expects us to know how to solve these linear congruences without using in verses.

Answer (score 0):

$x\equiv 3\pmod{17}\iff x=17k+3,\, k\in\Bbb Z$.

$17k+3\equiv 10\pmod{16}\iff 17k\equiv 7\pmod{16}$

$\iff k\equiv 7\pmod{16}\iff k=16m+7,\, m\in\Bbb Z$.

$x=17(16m+7)+3=272m+122$.

$272m+122\equiv 0\pmod{15}\iff 272m\equiv -2\pmod{15}$

$\iff 2m\equiv -2\pmod{15}\iff m\equiv -1\equiv 14\pmod{15}$

$\iff m=15c+14,\, c\in\Bbb Z$. $x=272(15c+14)+122=4080c+3930$.

Comment: Why does 17k get reduced to kmod 16?

Comment: @MichaelCera Definition of mod: $a\equiv b\pmod{n}$ means $n\mid a-b$. In this case, $17k\equiv k\pmod{16}$ because $16\mid 17k-k=k(17-1)=16k$.

Comment: ok I saw that! Now I attempted to solve this problem using your method and I actually got down all the way to 2m is congruent to -2mod15. How did that 2m become a m?

Comment: @MichaelCera I divided both sides by $2$. We know $15\mid 2m+2=2(m+1)$, also $\gcd(15,2)=1$, so $15 \mid m+1$ (by generalized Euclid's Lemma or common sense (remember Fundamental theorem of arithmetic)).